# Show that every number is the sum of at most 4 non null squares using Lagrange

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-factorization

In my attempts to learn about prime factorisation algorithms I came across [this](http://mathafou.free.fr/themes_en/ksumsq.html) (#1) and it is stated without proof, only the hint of it being related to Lagrange.

I don't know how to relate this to Lagrange's (Theorem?), nor any plan of attack to try reason it out.

Any hints are welcome :)

Comment: I think it means Lagrange's four square theorem, that all natural numbers are the sum of at most four square  numbers. I think Lagrange used Euler's four square identity to prove it (according to Wikipedia)...

Comment: A more "sophisticated" method consists in mimicking  the modern proof of Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares, replacing  the gaussian integers by the hamiltonian quaternions. See e.g. P. Samuel's "Algebraic Theory of Numbers", §5.7.